# Insert key on external keyboard not working on Double Commander

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, keybindings

I am new to Mac. The <kbd>Insert</kbd> key on my **external keyboard** is not working as expected.

I've got <kbd>Home</kbd> / <kbd>End</kbd> working [by adding DefaultKeyBinding.dict file](https://medium.com/@elhayefrat/how-to-fix-the-home-and-end-buttons-for-an-external-keyboard-in-mac-4da773a0d3a2)

How can I do the same for <kbd>Insert</kbd> (\UF727)?

Comment: Mac doesn't have an Insert key, or know how to respond to one. I'm also not sure why the linked article thinks home & end don't work on external keyboards. They've worked just fine here for the past two decades.